# Send Google Calendar events with different descriptions

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to create a google calendar event using the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events):

Each attendee should receive a different content in the description of the invite. Is there a way to pass description on attendee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*It is not possible to do this.*

#### More Information:

The information about an event is tied to the *event itself* in Google Calendar, rather than to the invite that is sent to the attendees. The invitation will have information contained within it about the event that it is related to. There is only one description, and so this same description will be sent to all attendees in the invitation.